# guice injector getInstance of annotated singleton instance

Tags: java, guice, restlet

I'm using Restlet with Guice.

A CachedThreadPool is definded in my Guice:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@Named("name0")
public ExecutorService provideAutoDisconnectThreadPool () {
    return Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
}
```

Wanted to shutdown the threadPool when the server is stops, so in my restlet.Application, I use injector to get the instance:

```
@Override
public void stop() throws Exception {
    LOGGER.info("stopping...");
    // shutdown threadPool
    injector.getInstance(ExecutorService.class).shutdown();
    super.stop();
    LOGGER.info("stopped");
}
```

However, the program got the error with:

```
com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:

1) No implementation for java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService was bound.
 while locating java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService

1 error
at    com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1004)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
```

So, how can I get the threadPool instance when application stops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Named` is a [binding annotation](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations), so injection key in this case is `ExecutorService.class` *and* `@Named("name0")`:

```
injector.getInstance(Key.get(ExecutorService.class, Names.named("name0")))
```

Comment: that works, <T> T getInstance(Key<T> var1) is the solution, thx